# Xamarin iOS Splashscreen not showing

Tags: ios, xamarin, splash-screen

If followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos

The LaunchScreen never shows up. I am using VS2019 for Mac current build. Followed all instructions to the letter.

**Update:**

github sample project as requested.

https://github.com/tpitman/Xamarin-Forms-SplashScreenTest

I created a new cross platform forms solution. I downloaded an image of the Xamarin logo. The project already has a LaunchScreen.storyboard. It also already had an image view object, but I deleted that and added a new one because the steps on that link above said to add one. I also added the label just like those instructions say.

You will notice when you run it that the label shows up, but the image does not. That is the problem. In my app I don't have or need a label. I just have an image I want to show.

**Update 2:**
I deleted the above repo. Created a new project including Android this time (not sure that matters, but it represents my real situation).

I also changed the image I used from the stock one to my own in case that matters.

I then built it and it does NOT work as the original one didn't. Hopefully it won't work for you as well.

I also created a video of it not working. Here is the link to that video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uy0KfDq0_5IfrqDDaMVDNeGylibzUH5m/view?usp=sharing

**Update 3:**
In the end I am not sure what fix it. I removed and reimported the images. I have 3 projects and 2 of them work fine now using the Assets.xcasset method and the other one I couldn't get to work that way, but works with the images being in the Resources folder.

I think one thing that I did that seemed to make a difference was I did a clean and then build and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Hi, could you share a sample project link here? I will check that in my visual studio.

Comment: I will see if I can come up with a sample project that does this. I would assume it would just be to follow the guide in that link I included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the shared github sample project, it works in my local site. Both in **VS for Mac** (`8.8.4`) and **VS for PC**(`16.8.3`).

[image]

==================================Update================================

There is a workaround to solve that, you could add Image to **Resouces** directly.

[image]

Then use it in **LaunchScreen.Storyboard**, then it will show:

[image]

Comment: Ok this is really weird. The first time I ran it it didn't work. Now it does. I also have my actual application that still isn't working and uses the same process of the the example. I am confused.

Comment: Is there a way that I can share my project in a private way with you so you can take a look at it?

Comment: I decided to take a different approach. I deleted that repository (sorry if that messes anyone up). I then created a new Xamarin Forms cross platform project. This time I included Android because that is my real case. i don't know if that is part of it. I then changed the image to my actual splash screen image. I then built this and it does NOT show the splash screen. I also made a video of starting up this app to show it not working and uploaded that video. I will post another update with that link...

Comment: @user856232 Sorry, I can not check your private project. But from shared video, you are running it in a physical device. And the splash screen not shows when launching the application. I suggest that modify the image name with a new specified name to check whether it works. You could have a look at these discussions: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125102 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650913

Comment: You don't need to check my private project. I ended up changing directions and deleted the previous repo you looked at and recreated it. Please take a look at the same repo, but after you delete it and reclone it. Also, that video is not from an actual device. It is in the simulator. I did a quicktime recording of the screen. The recreated repo is the new app with a different splash screen as shown in the video not working. If it works for you then I will be totally confused because as you see in the video it did not work for me.

Comment: @user856232 I have checked in my other forms projects. It also works. When you add image in storyboard, whether you can see the image shows inside it? If so, it should work. You also could have a try with a Xamarin.iOS project to check whether it works.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos#related-links

Comment: Are you saying you tried may latest one I checked in or your own? If you have not checked mine please do so.

Comment: @user856232 Yes, your updated repo shows a blcak launch screen when running.

Comment: @user856232 But there is a workaround for it. You could add Image file inside **Resources** folder, not add in **Asserts**. Then it will show.

Comment: I am at a loss now. I did what you did in that sample app and sure enough it works. So I try to do the same thing in my own app and it doesn't work. I created a video showing this. I don't know what to do. I can't give you my actual app project. There has to be something that is causing it. Please see this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFlWtmukHKQFmM1OxdcgnGDO7xMTF8lX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user856232 Hi, it's strange. It seems like an issue for vs. The workaround works for me, therefore I also have no idea about this. Maybe you could add a renamed imgae to `Resources` to check again. Maybe VS will mess the similar named image of `Resources` with `Assets`.

Comment: I think you are right. I did a bunch of playing around with different things this morning and am not sure what fixed it. One of the things I did was to reimport the images into the Assets.xcassets object and do a clean all. I think the clean all was critical. So I am now not using the work around and it is working. Very strange.

Comment: @user856232 Anyway, that's great! It's a strange phenomenon for VS. If you have solved that, you could vote up my answer. You also could update your answer and mark it when you have time.